# Java Mail API Cannot Read Inbox

Tags: java, email, outlook

I had tried to implement a simple program which reads outlook inbox using pop3 protocol but the server returns me zero mail even there is 2 unread mail. Why is this problem? Is it relate to Microsoft Exchange server settings?

```
public void retrieveEmail() {
        // JavaMail API - Exchange server to allow IMAP access

        // mail server connection parameters
        String user = "";
        String password = "";

        // connect to my pop3 inbox
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "110");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.user", user);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.timeout", "158000");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.connectiontimeout", "158000");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
        session.setDebug(true);

        Store store = null;
        Folder inbox = null;

        try {
            store = session.getStore("pop3");
            store.connect(host, user, password);
            inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // get the list of inbox messages
            int totalMsg = inbox.getMessageCount();
            int unread = inbox.getUnreadMessageCount();
            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
            Message[] msg = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));

            System.out.print("size " + messages .length);
            if (messages.length == 0) System.out.println("No messages found.");

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                // stop after listing ten messages
                if (i > 10) {
                    System.exit(0);
                    inbox.close(true);
                    store.close();
                }

                System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("From : " + messages[i].getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Subject : " + messages[i].getSubject());
                Object content = messages[i].getContent();

                if (content instanceof String)  
                    System.out.print((String)content);  
                /* text/plain = String
                 * multipart" = Multipart
                 * MimeMessage
                 * input stream = Unknown Data Handler 
                 */

            }

            inbox.close(true);
            store.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
```

EDIT 1:

I debugging it and realize that variable total in Folder is zero

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I just hope that you did not post your production username + password...

Comment: Why Java Mail API cannot fetch message from Microsoft exchange server even though outlook shows there are plenty of email?

Comment: Maybe you're missing some auth params... have you checked: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#Exchange-login

Comment: Are you sure your pop3 port is 110 and not 25?

Comment: Also, which version of j2ee are you using 1.3? or 1.4?

Comment: What other command available to test a POP3 server besides telnet which uses to retrieve email and connect to it?

Comment: No exception is thrown; it just thinks there are no messages?  This may not the problem but I'd consider using IMAP instead of POP.  IMAP is more modern.

Comment: Cannot change protocol. I debugging it and realize that variable total in Folder is zero.

Comment: Can you get server side log to see if there is a missconfigurated path, is your folder Inbox the right name?

Answer (score 0):

Ask your email administrator what the exchange value for 'alias' is for the above email account. If they, for example have the value set as 'Bananas!' then you must change the above code to read store.getFolder("Bananas!") instead of store.getFolder("Inbox");